Installation of older version of QGIS in conda environment: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.25
For a given experimental plugin, I need to install python 3.9 and the older LTR qgis 3.28.9 into a separate conda environment. I do:
conda create -y -n ximena-env -c conda-forge python=3.9
conda activate ximena-env
conda install conda-forge::qgis=3.28.9

But then,
$ qgis
qgis: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I solve this?
Edit1:
Following the suggestion by user2856, I get a qgis crash:
$ conda create -y -n ximena-env -c conda-forge python=3.9 qgis=3.28.9
$ conda activate ximena-env
$ qgis                                                                                                           
(PDAL Error) Can't load library /home/alobo/miniconda3/envs/ximena-env/lib/libpdal_plugin_reader_draco.so: Failed to load "/home/alobo/miniconda3/envs/ximena-env/lib/libpdal_plugin_reader_draco.so": libdraco.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory(PDAL Error) Can't load library /home/alobo/miniconda3/envs/ximena-env/lib/libpdal_plugin_writer_draco.so: Failed to load "/home/alobo/miniconda3/envs/ximena-env/lib/libpdal_plugin_writer_draco.so": libdraco.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directoryPyQt5 (Qt 5.15.9) 
3.9.18 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Aug 30 2023, 04:04:13)                                                                            
[GCC 12.3.0]                                                                                                                                
Warning: Cannot open file '/home/alobo/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/XYZHubConnector/images/bbox.svg', because: No such file or directory                                                                                                                     
Warning: Cannot open file '/home/alobo/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/XYZHubConnector/images/bbox.svg', because: No such file or directory
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

If I omit python=3.9, I get the 1st part of the error messages but not the crash:
$ conda create -y -n ximena-env -c conda-forge qgis=3.28.9
$ conda activate ximena-env
$ qgis                                                                                                                         
(PDAL Error) Can't load library /home/alobo/miniconda3/envs/ximena-env/lib/libpdal_plugin_reader_draco.so: Failed to load "/home/alobo/miniconda3/envs/ximena-env/lib/libpdal_plugin_reader_draco.so": libdraco.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory(PDAL Error) Can't load library /home/alobo/miniconda3/envs/ximena-env/lib/libpdal_plugin_writer_draco.so: Failed to load "/home/alobo/miniconda3/envs/ximena-env/lib/libpdal_plugin_writer_draco.so": libdraco.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directoryPyQt5 (Qt 5.15.9)
3.11.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Oct  3 2023, 11:02:03) [GCC 12.3.0]
Warning: Cannot open file '/home/alobo/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/XYZHubConnector/images/bbox.svg', because: No such file or directory
Warning: Cannot open file '/home/alobo/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/XYZHubConnector/images/bbox.svg', because: No such file or directory

The problem is that, in this latter case, I get python 3.11 automatically installed, and I need 3.9 for compatibility with the libraries I must install for the experimental plugin afterward.

I don't know if this should be an answer as your method worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 with miniforge conda.  However, it's easier to break an existing environment than create a broken env from scratch. So try specifying your requirements when you create the env, instead of installing QGIS afterwards. This lets conda figure out all the dependencies in one go rather than having to figure out dependencies twice (faster and more reliable) and then having to download the new requirements plus changed or downgraded dependencies.  conda create -y -n ximena-env -c conda-forge python=3.9 qgis=3.28.9
